# Fog issue using iam profile and fetching urls from aws

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, carrierwave, fog

Using Fog w/ AWS instance profiles and after 3 day my s3 urls are no longer working. I'm getting fresh urls, but the error returned from AWS is The provided token has expired. Restarting the application gets everything working again, but no errors other than the one from AWS are present.

I have read that switching to keys should fix my issue, but I was hoping to keep my iam profile. Has anyone run into this?

my Carrierwave config is bellow and I am using Carrierwave version 0.9.0 and Fog 1.28.0

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',
    :region                 => 'us-east-1',
    :path_style             => true,
    :host                   => 's3-external-1.amazonaws.com'    # routes all requests to Northern Virginia datacenter
  }

  if defined?(Settings.use_iam_profile) && Settings.use_iam_profile
    fog_credentials[:use_iam_profile] = true
  else
    fog_credentials[:aws_access_key_id] = Settings.s3_access_key
    fog_credentials[:aws_secret_access_key] = Settings.s3_secret_key
  end

  config.fog_credentials = fog_credentials
  config.fog_directory  = Settings.s3_bucket_name                 # required
  config.fog_public     = false                                   # optional, defaults to true
  config.root = File.join(Rails.root, 'private')
end
```

Comment: Can you show us your carrierwave configuration? I've been using carrierwave with IAM profiles without any issues. Which version of fog and carrierwave are you using?

Comment: @makhan I updated the question with that info

Comment: Nothing obvious comes to mind. Do you have `ntp` up and running on this server? If the problem is only with reading, would it be an option to make the folders public readable?

Comment: @makhan we can't make the folders public due to what they contain, ntp seems to be running. I remember reading that could be the issue if the time got out of sync and that restarting the application fixes that issue, but that shouldn't be the issue because we are hosting it on ec2

Comment: Sorry, I don't know fog and carrierwave well enough to help you. You could try using `carrierwave-aws`, not sure how well it works though.

Comment: @makhan They just submitted  pull request to fog to fix this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this [link](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/1547#issuecomment-97142584) got updated, basically the issue was While the signing token was being refreshed correctly when downloading files with fog, it wasn't being refreshed when signing an S3 URL.

There was a [pull request](https://github.com/fog/fog-aws/pull/103) made on fog to fix this issue